# regex if length greater than n then if starts with

Tags: c#, regex, validation, url

I try to use Regex validate textbox input

`string pattern = @"^.{8,}|https?\:\/\/.+$";`

First check input minimum length is >= 8

In case (http://) or (https://)

Then check the input is starts with `http://` or `https://`

I searched some answer said that should use `|` pipe character to do if-else

but not works in my case

Tester: https://regex101.com/r/yI0dR6/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of alternation, you need a positive-lookahead for making sure a minimum length of 8:

```
string pattern = @"^(?=.{8})https?://.+$";
```

`(?=.{8})` is a positive lookahead that makes sure there are at least 8 characters in your input.